# Pandas DataFrame Outputting Too Many Columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a small program to take a .txt file output of a router's 'Show ARP' command, perform a natural sort on a user chosen column (Either IP, MAC, or VLAN), and then output it into a .csv file.

Currently I'm having issues outputting from a variable (either string or list) into the dataframe. It either comes out in a single column, or too many where words are split into columns of individual letters.

Example data:

```
Protocol  Address          Age (min)  Hardware Addr   Type   Interface
Internet  10.0.1.1               -   0000.0000.0001  ARPA   Vlan900
Internet  10.0.2.1               -   0000.0000.0002  ARPA   Vlan900
Internet  10.0.20.1              0   Incomplete      ARPA
Internet  10.2.0.1                -   0000.0001.0000  ARPA   Vlan95
Internet  10.3.0.2              255   0000.0002.0000  ARPA   Vlan1
Internet  10.4.0.1              10   0000.0003.0000  ARPA   Vlan2
Internet  10.4.0.10              1   0000.0004.0000  ARPA   Vlan10
```

```
with open(inputfilepath,"r") as inputfile:
    lines = inputfile.read()

lines = re.sub("\s{2,}",",",lines) #Replace 2+ spaces with a comma. Creates a string
lines2 = re.split("\n",lines) #Creates a list
headers = lines2[0].split(",") #Create headers in a list
```

```
#dataframe1 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(lines,columns=headers)
```

Above creates 1 column, but it should be 6

```
#dataframe1 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(lines2,columns=headers)
```

Above creates 55 columns, instead of 6. Each word is split into individual letters for some reason (removed headers to discover this)
.

```
dataframe1 = pd.read_csv(inputfilepath, delimiter = "\s{2,}", engine="python")


#dataframe1.to_excel(outputfilepath)
dataframe1.to_csv(outputfilepath,index=None)
```

If I use regex here to just read it directly from the text file and then dump into a CSV, it seems to work fine. However I haven't been able to find a way to manipulate the data with natsorted inside the dataframe - likely as I'm just not familiar with Pandas.

Trying to output directly to Excel resulted in a 'No engine for filetype csv' error, outputting directly to CSV works without issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert IP addresses to numeric values to use `sort_values`:

```
import numpy as np

df['AddressNum'] = np.left_shift(df['Address'].str.split('.', expand=True).astype(int), [24, 16, 8, 0]).sum(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   Protocol    Address Age (min)   Hardware Addr  Type Interface  AddressNum
0  Internet   10.0.1.1         -  0000.0000.0001  ARPA   Vlan900   167772417
1  Internet   10.0.2.1         -  0000.0000.0002  ARPA   Vlan900   167772673
2  Internet  10.0.20.1         0      Incomplete  ARPA      None   167777281
3  Internet   10.2.0.1         -  0000.0001.0000  ARPA    Vlan95   167903233
4  Internet   10.3.0.2       255  0000.0002.0000  ARPA     Vlan1   167968770
5  Internet   10.4.0.1        10  0000.0003.0000  ARPA     Vlan2   168034305
6  Internet  10.4.0.10         1  0000.0004.0000  ARPA    Vlan10   168034314
```

Alternative using `natsort`:

```
from natsort import natsort_key

>>> df.sort_values('Interface', key=natsort_key)
   Protocol    Address Age (min)   Hardware Addr  Type Interface
2  Internet  10.0.20.1         0      Incomplete  ARPA      None
4  Internet   10.3.0.2       255  0000.0002.0000  ARPA     Vlan1
5  Internet   10.4.0.1        10  0000.0003.0000  ARPA     Vlan2
6  Internet  10.4.0.10         1  0000.0004.0000  ARPA    Vlan10
3  Internet   10.2.0.1         -  0000.0001.0000  ARPA    Vlan95
0  Internet   10.0.1.1         -  0000.0000.0001  ARPA   Vlan900
1  Internet   10.0.2.1         -  0000.0000.0002  ARPA   Vlan900
```

---

**Old answer**

Try to use `pd.read_csv` with another separator:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.txt', sep='\s\s+', engine='python')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   Protocol    Address Age (min)   Hardware Addr  Type Interface
0  Internet   10.0.1.1         -  0000.0000.0001  ARPA   Vlan900
1  Internet   10.0.2.1         -  0000.0000.0002  ARPA   Vlan900
2  Internet  10.0.20.1         0      Incomplete  ARPA      None
3  Internet   10.2.0.1         -  0000.0001.0000  ARPA    Vlan95
4  Internet   10.3.0.2       255  0000.0002.0000  ARPA     Vlan1
5  Internet   10.4.0.1        10  0000.0003.0000  ARPA     Vlan2
6  Internet  10.4.0.10         1  0000.0004.0000  ARPA    Vlan10

>>> df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 7 entries, 0 to 6
Data columns (total 6 columns):
 #   Column         Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------         --------------  ----- 
 0   Protocol       7 non-null      object
 1   Address        7 non-null      object
 2   Age (min)      7 non-null      object
 3   Hardware Addr  7 non-null      object
 4   Type           7 non-null      object
 5   Interface      6 non-null      object
dtypes: object(6)
memory usage: 464.0+ bytes
```